# Good coupling intuitions between microstrip line and cylindrical dielectric resonator

Tags: resonance

I am trying to get a good coupling between microstrip resonator and cylindrical dielectric resonator.

I know it's a sort of transformer equivalent model.

I am moving the dielectric cylinder around the microstrip line and I don't have a clue how to get the best coupling.

I have read many article and the touch this manner very vague.

I am trying to look at the field monitor or the current distribution.

Is there any practical advice how I can see by field monitors or current distribution the sweet spot where my dielectric resonator will couple the best to the microstrip feeding?

Comment: Lub2354, I realized English may not be your first language, but please try to capitalize and spell correctly. It will help readability of your questions and garner better attention and answers. See the edits for details.